# Textarea without wysiwyg editor but have nice format

Tags: php, textarea

I have a textarea where someone can input text. I do not want a wysiwyg editor.

But what would be great:

Strip all tags, but make correct `<p>` and `<br />` if user input has new lines.
Additionally convert all urls, with or without http// or parameter to clickable links.

I cannot find a solution.

So you could type into the textarea:

```
........
This is a paragraph
This ist still in the paragraph

this is a new paragraph www.this-would-be-clickable

new paragraphp `<strong>`this will be shown not bold`</strong>`
........
```

thankfull for every advice

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CKEditor. It may be more than what you need, but still very good.
http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: yes, it is indeed more than what I need. Thats why I do not want an editor

Answer (score 0):

Another more simplistic alternative is [Wymeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/).

Seems to me that Markdown or Textile would get you a long way, though.

But if all you need is the newline/paragraph control and url to link, you could easily build it yourself with some regex.

Comment: I had a look on wymeditor, but I would prefer the regex solution. 
Maybe someone could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a function inside a famous blog software..... plus this regex for links, the regex seems to work, but most probably there are better solution:

/((http(s?)://)|(www.))([^\s()[]<>]+|([^\s)]*)|[[^\s]]*])+(?